# Asp.Net core 2.2.6 Deployment issues on plesk

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am deploying my asp.net core 2.2 project to a domain of plesk account. I am facing 500.0 error.

I am working in netcoreapp2.2 with corehostingModel "InProcess", its working fine locally mean at iis its working fine, But when i deploy it on my domain of plesk account, it is giving this error

HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure
Common causes of this issue:
The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.
The in process request handler, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS, was not referenced in the application.
ANCM could not find dotnet.
Troubleshooting steps:

Comment: Since you speak of IIS, I assume you run Windows Server 2016/2019 with Plesk? Error message is pretty clear actually, you need to install the .NET Core SDK on your server. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2. For self containing applications, The "Runtime & Hosting Bundle" is required (it contains ANCM - ASP.NET Core Module for IIS)

Comment: But since you are getting `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` its seems to be a portable App, so the SDK needs (which also contains the .NET Core 2.2 runtime) to be installed on the target system

Comment: I Actuallu resolved it by removing "InProcess" model from web.config

Comment: Well its not a solution if your goal was to use InProcess hosting :P Though in 99.9% of all cases it won't make any difference. InProcess hosting is for increased performance in high traffic webapplications (like 10k requests per second)